# Rerun the name of the plot cannot show but shows Error in check_aesthetics(): ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8): label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a weird problem. I am using ggplot2 to generate 12 biplot figures for 12 RDA (Redundancy analysis). Please see the below code for one figure.

Here I attach the data and full code in the google drive https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ohO62-2jmMzVjJo2JLZOo8ffabzBx-8S?usp=sharing

```
plot1 <-ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = sp,aes(RDA1,RDA2),shape=21,size=4,fill="tomato2")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set2')+
  geom_text_repel(data = sp,aes(RDA1,RDA2,label=sp2$Group),color="tomato1",size=4.5)+
  geom_point(data = yz,aes(RDA1,RDA2),size=3,shape=24,fill="dodgerblue3")+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(22:23))+
  geom_text_repel(data = yz,aes(RDA1,RDA2,label=yz2$label),color="dodgerblue2",size=4.5)+
  labs(x=paste("RDA 1 (", format(100 *ii$cont[[1]][2,1], digits=3), "%)", sep=""),
       y=paste("RDA 2 (", format(100 *ii$cont[[1]][2,2], digits=3), "%)", sep=""))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,linetype=3,size=1,color="gray50") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0,linetype=3,size=1,color="gray50")+
  guides(shape=guide_legend(title=NULL,color="black"),
         fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))+
  theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 13)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black",size=14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black",size=14)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black",size=14),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black",size=14)) 
plot1
```

The problem is that when I finished running the code for the first figure (plot1), I could see the first figure by running `plot1`. However, when after I finished running the code for the other figures (plot3 or 4 or 5..., not exact one, very randomly), I rerun `plot1`, it came out an error said **Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8): label
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.** Also, this kind of error comes out quite randomly. For plot1, sometimes there is no error. Sometimes this error shows.

Comment: Is there some point in your plotting code where you modify or update the `sp2` or `yz2` external data frames? Because I imagine this might give such an error.

Comment: Your problem is not *reproducible* on the code (or data) you (haven't) given us so far.  So it's going to be diffucult to do anything other than offer hypotheticals.  Clearly something has changed, but we have no way of identifying exactly what it is.

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to provide a minimal reproducible dataset for us to work with. One way is by using `dput`. You can see how to use this command in the following video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I do not think the dataframes of sp2 or yz2 is changed. The code was successful without any errors when I used another dataset. It is queit strange that after I use another dataset with the same names of variables but less sample size caused this issue. @teunbrand

Comment: Yeah I don't think we'll be able  to solve this based on your description alone. If you're looking for a solution, it is best to provide (dummy) data and code that reproduces your error, while cutting out on things that are irrelevant for the error (e.g. theme and guide specifications and annotations, I imagine).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for not providing detailed data and code. I attach the data and code in the google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ohO62-2jmMzVjJo2JLZOo8ffabzBx-8S?usp=sharing) @Limey

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for not providing detailed data and code. I attach the data and code in the google drive link @teunbrand

Comment: @JieSU You could try using `geom_debug()` from package 'gginnards'. Instead of adding a plot layer this "unusual" geom prints a dump of its data input to the R console. Depending on the stage at which the error is triggered, this geom can help (or not) with finding problems with mappings.

Before that, check if the problems disapears if you comment out one by one the lines of code that add layers to the plot.

Comment: As the error is triggered intermitently, a possible source of it is `geom_text_repel()`. To be sure change it temporarily into `geom_text()`. (`geom_text_repel()` algorithm depends in part on random number generation.)